# .NET Centralized Configuration for Windows Services and WCF Web Services

Tags: c#, wcf, configurationmanager

Does anybody know of a way to centralize a .NET app config so that it can be used by multiple windows services and multiple wcf web services on a computer? They are all installed in separate folders under \program files. Our software currently has a separate app config for each application but it's getting crazy trying to maintain it all.

We have though of having each application reference a gac dll that can read from a central file but that will probably not work due to the wcf client configuration for those apps that call wcf web services.

For example we will typically have 2 or more wcf webservices and/or 2 or more windows services on a computer and they each have their own configuration files.

tia

Answer (score 2):

.NET configuration file can [reference another](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228154.aspx) config file. If your apps are deployed similar to this:

```
Program Files \ MyCompany \ Shared.config
Program Files \ MyCompany \ ClientA \ ClientA.config
```

You can reference `Shared.config` from `ClientA.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    ...
    <appSettings file="..\Shared.config">
```

You can also try putting settings into [machine.config](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229697%28v=VS.90%29.aspx). From [Configuring Services Using Configuration Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733932.aspx):

> ... This mechanism allows machine-wide settings to be defined in the
>   Machine.config file. The App.config file can be used to override the
>   settings of the Machine.config file; you can also lock in the settings
>   in Machine.config file so that they get used.

Comment: only issue here would be ease of deployment.